# How can I host a Laravel-PHP API and React frontend on Azure, while passing .env data in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service, virtual-machine, private-subnet

I'd like to create a Laravel-PHP API service that is hosted on the Azure cloud, and I also need the front end react to be hosted on Azure. Can anyone help?

I tried using the Azure app service, but I'm not sure how to get through.env datas to app service is also receiving a build error indicating that the php version is incompatible. Can someone offer a solution for hosting the php-Laravel framework on the Azure cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your `.env` values in [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal).
If you have secrets, it's best to use an Azure Key Vault and make a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) from your app settings to an Azure KeyVault.

You can get the available PHP versions:

```
az webapp list-runtimes --os linux | grep PHP
"PHP:8.2",
"PHP:8.1",
"PHP:8.0",
```

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux) for **Laravel** specifics on Azure App Service.